# Security of SimpleMemberShip

Tags: asp.net, simplemembership

I have a question. I am looking at the newly implemented Simple Membership Provider and it suits my needs out of the box. I am however a little concerned about this provider as I am looking at creating a custom web application for myself and would like to know the security pros and cons of using it and if there is any best practices to go about building a secure web application. Is simple membership secure ? I am a noob when it comes to security.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not writing your own authentication and session management routines.  Security is difficult and any flaws in your design or code could lead to exposure or breaches.

We have used Simple Membership in several web portals that handle PHI (protected health information).  Our clients routinely audit our development methods and none so far have considered this a risk.  Had we developed our own, they would raise a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can get further by creating a library class of helper functions to add the features you feel are missing from existing providers, or subclass an existing provider (I don't think they are sealed/final).

In any case, your first step would be to draw up a list of features you want, check to see if an existing provider already does that (for example if you want an XML file provider, one exists on CodePlex), and if none do, either extend or write your own.  If you write your own, you would want to make sure that there is another layer of security, like being on an intranet, or local access only or some other layer of defense.